# v4.4 Multiline chart _ crashes with undefined

Tags: crash, chart.js, multiline, stacked

It crashes on line 277 of core.datasetController.js

Why am I even there?

The property it is handling seems to be fill but I don't understand why?

I am effectively trying to display 6 lines with the same x-axis using stacked on the y-axis

Any ideas?
Pete

I've used the debugging features of Chrome which is why I know where the crash happens but not why.`
Here's my code:

```
<body>
<div id="chart-container">
<canvas id="graphCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {showGraph();});

function showGraph()
{$.post("data_stacked.php",function (data)
{
    console.log(data);
    var tags = [];
    var annee = [];
    var number = [];
    var data_set = [];
    var backgroundColors = [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
                ];
    i = 0;
    data_array=JSON.parse(data);
    Object.keys(data_array).forEach(key => {
    annee = [];
    number =[];
    college = key;
    let element = new Object();
    Object.keys(data_array[college]).forEach(key => {
        annee.push(key);
        if (!tags.includes(key)) tags.push(key);
        element = data_array[college][key];
        number.push(element);
    });
    data_set[i] = [
    {
    label: college,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColors[i],
    stack:'combined',
    type:'line',
    fill: false,
    borderColor: '#46d5f1',
    hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
    hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
    data: number
    }];
    i++;
    }); 
    
var chartdata = {
    labels: tags,
    datasets: data_set,
    options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
        stacked: true
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Adhérents'
        }
    }
    }
}
    
var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");
console.log(chartdata);
var Graph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata
});
});
}    
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think I have understood the problem. A not fully populated array i.e. certain values were missing if not present in the database from which I was taking the data. PROBLEM SOLVED